# 1 Header File, 3 CPP Files. Where do you put the common functions?

Tags: c++

Let's assume I have the following files:

- polygon.h
- rectangle.cpp
- triangle.cpp
- circle.cpp

Rectangle, Triangle, and Circle will all have different implementation of `calculateArea`, but they all sharing the same function of `getNumSides`. Where do you put `getNumSides`?

Would be good if someone can help me design this

Comment: diffentiate FILES and classes, and then declaration and definition

Comment: can you elaborate, and may be giving a simple code structure? @JacekCz

Comment: Add an abstract class called Shape. Move the common function definitions there, and have the other classes inherit it.

Comment: it depends on which variables you use inside the function. if it defies anonymity then should be inside cpp files.

Comment: Abstract class is probably the best method.

Comment: 1. classes/objects have not function. 2. Impossible to write in SO book or every CPP tutor. This is basic information, You should learn by-self.

Comment: Abstract class in a new file, or even in your header file if you dont want to create a new file

Comment: The design depends on the purpose. What is the purpose of your code? Are you writing a library? What public interface do you want it to have? Code layout decisions are secondary and not really that important. So, if your question is C++ only, you must be much more specific. If your question is about general design, perhaps [softwareengineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) is a better place for this question, but would also need to be more specific about purpose.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many sides do you specify that a circle has?

Comment: @Frax when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make abstract class polygon and define `getNumSides()` inside it. The function `calculateArea()` should be pure virtual function inside class `polygon`. When you derive `rectangle`, `triangle` and `circle` classes, put the implementation of `calculateArea()` inside those.

Comment: what this answer has to FILES, as question state?

Comment: Base class functions would go into polygon.cpp, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

A common scheme is to keep one header/source file *per class*, and have the base file name indicate the name of the class it contains, e.g.

class Polygon is declared in a header named Polygon.h, and its source in Polygon.cpp, class Rectangle in Rectangle.h and Rectangle.cpp etc..

Any other scheme seem to cause some headaches as you start having many classes.